# Why python shows error for a similar method but with different syntax where one of them works fine but another one give error as shown below

Tags: python, string, list

```
letters=["A","B","C"..............,"X","Y"]
password_list=[]

for i in range(1 , 5):
         password_list += random.choice(letters) <--- No error
```

is working but,

```
password_list=[]

for i in range(1 , 5):
         password_list = password_list +  random.choice(letters) <--- error
```

giving error of cannot concatenate string, if both are same just syntax is different then why it is giving error?

can someone explain this briefly?

PS:- if required i will attach the Screenshot of problem.

Thank you

Comment: not a [mre]:  NameError on `nr_letters, letters` + missing imports. Why iterate over `for char in range(1,nr_letters+1)`  and never use `char` (which is a number, not a char) instead of iterating `for _ in range(nr_letters):` wich iterates as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `__iadd__` i.e., *in-place add* method of the list `password_list` is called and it can work with *any* iterable e.g., a string in your case.

In the other one `__add__` method of `password_list` is called and it can *only* work with lists, which `random.choice(letters)` isn't one.

Another difference is that first one doesn't make any new list; it changes the place where `password_list` looks at. Second one, however, generates a brand new list *and* then makes `password_list` look at there.

---

samples:

```
>>> a = [12, 51]
>>> a += range(2)    # *any* iterable
>>> a
[12, 51, 0, 1]

>>> a += ("this", "that")
>>> a
[12, 51, 0, 1, "this", "that"]

>>> a += "strings"
>>> a
[12, 51, 0, 1, "this", "that", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", "s"]

>>> a = a + (64, 23)
# TypeError... Even tuples are not acceptable; it must be a list
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not equivalent.

The `+=` operator on a list calls the `__iadd__` magic method, which does accept single valued arguments.

The `+` operator on a list calls the `__add__` magic method, that just expects another iterable.

```
l = []

l.__iadd__('s') # no error
l.__add__('s') # Error
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably trying to concattenate a string to a list - wich is an error!

> ```
> import random       # interpolated - missing in your post
>
> password_list = []  # this is a list
> letters = "abcdefg" # interpolated - missing in your post
> nr_letters = 25     # interpolated - missing in your post
>
> for _ in range(nr_letters):
>      # tries to concat a random string to your list
>      password_list = password_list + random.choice(letters)
> ```

Fix:

```
 import random

 password_list = []  # this is a list
 letters = "abcdefg" # interpolated - missing in your post
 nr_letters = 25     # interpolated - missing in your post

 for _ in range(nr_letters):
      password_list = password_list + [random.choice(letters)] 
      # password_list.append(random.choice(letters))

 # or better:

 password_list = random.choices(letters, k=nr_letters)
```

That `password_list += random.choice(letters)` works is because it is similar to `password_list.append(random.choice(letters))`